# Bluemix IoTF connection error - Python

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot, tls1.2

Friends,

I have created a device in IBM Bluemix IoTF, generated authentication tokens and everything is set. I am trying to connect and send messages to this device using Python (ibm-iotf library) and the program has been created. But when I run the program, I am getting the following errors. Please help.

```
2016-03-21 11:04:15,786 ibmiotf.device.Client WARNING Unable to encrypt messages because TLSv1.2 is unavailable (MQTT over SSL requires at least Python v2.7.9 or 3.4 and openssl v1.0.1)

[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

2016-03-21 11:04:16,446 ibmiotf.device.Client ERROR Unexpected disconnect from the IBM Internet of Things Foundation

2016-03-21 11:04:16,446 ibmiotf.device.Client INFO Messages published : 0, life: 1s, rate: 1/0.00s

2016-03-21 11:04:16,446 ibmiotf.device.Client INFO Messages received : 0, life: 1s, rate: 1/0.00s
```

Comment: It very clearly says that you need to have at least Python 2.7.9 or 3.4 and OpenSSL 1.0.1, otherwise TLSv1.2 does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/devices/mqtt.html): The IoT Platform requires TLS v1.2. We suggest the following cipher suites: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, AES256-GCM-SHA384, ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 or AES128-GCM-SHA256.

Ensure you have Python version and Open SSL 1.0.1 which provides support for TLS v1.2